# ament_flake8 fails with AttributeError

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run `ament_flake8` in my workspace.

This is what I do

```
mkdir -p ws/src 
git clone MY_REPO ws/src/repo
cd ws
colcon build
ament_flake8 .
```

And I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/eloquent/bin/ament_flake8",
> line 11, in 
> load_entry_point('ament-flake8==0.8.1',
> 'console_scripts', 'ament_flake8')()
> File
> "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_flake8/main.py",
> line 75, in main
> max_line_length=args.linelength)   File
> "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_flake8/main.py",
> line 163, in generate_flake8_report
> style = get_flake8_style_guide(flake8_argv)
> File
> "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_flake8/main.py",
> line 131, in get_flake8_style_guide
> application.parse_preliminary_options_and_args([])
> AttributeError: 'Application' object
> has no attribute
> 'parse_preliminary_options_and_args'

Note that if instead I run `flake8 .` this works as expected.

I'm using a Dockerfile `FROM osrf/ros:eloquent-desktop`

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353448/ament_flake8-fails-with-attributeerror/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2020-05-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A recent release of `flake8` (3.8) broke API the `ament_flake8` package uses. You can:

- either use an older version of `flake8` (< 3.8) or
- wait for the patch to `ament_flake8` to be backported to Eloquent (https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/pull/242).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2020-05-29**:
Thank you, this command did the job

```
pip install -Iv flake8==3.7
```